# What will happen to my wife's debt when she passes away?

Tags: debt, debt-collection, death

I am currently a Washington state resident but my wife is still an Oregon resident. Recently she has had some health issues and has been given a short amount of time left to live. We are trying to figure out what will happen to her student loan and credit card debt when she passes away.

I know Washington is a community property state, but Oregon is not. Which state's laws do we fall under?

- We do not own a home or any property.
- Her credit card debt and student loans are in her name only.
- We have no children/dependents.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a specific legal advice. You'll need to talk to a lawyer familiar with the Oregon and Washington State laws, and check the specifics of the loan terms. At the least, her estate will be liable, but you may be as well.

Comment: I disagree. In my opinion, debt is on-topic, as are the rules (laws) regarding inheritance. I don't know the answer to the OP's question, but it strikes me as both on topic and a decent question.

Comment: @littleadv I can see your point, and we do have plans to meet with a lawyer. My goal in posting here is to try and become a little more familiar with the process and maybe even discover more questions I should be asking when we do meet with the lawyer. By no means are we considering advice given here as a replacement for professional legal advice, but were hoping to learn something from some people who have had similar experiences. If there are any edits/additions you think should be made to my post in order to make it more suitable, let me know and I'll do my best to incorporate them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Federal Student Loans

Federal Student Loans are discharged with the borrower's death, regardless of who co-signed the loan.

### PLUS Loans (and Parent PLUS Loans)

PLUS loans are discharged on the death of the borrower. In the case of Parent PLUS Loans, if the parent(s) out-live the student, the loan can be discharged through the Death Discharge application. (Parent(s) may be subject to Cancellation of Debt Income (CODI) tax liability. Consult your local tax professional)

### Private Student Loans / Credit Cards

Private loans and credit cards are not required to discharge debts upon the death of a borrower. Depending on the lender, they may attempt to collect against your wife's estate (community property) and you may need to seek out an estate lawyer for more specifics. My research shows that banks will often evaluate each on a case-by-case basis, depending on the amount of the debt and the assets.

I can't find any references about spouses living in separate states, at least for property law, and each state has wildly different laws. So depending on the amount of private loan and/or credit card debt, you may owe that (and want to pay it to avoid legal fees), but if the amount is quite high, you should consult an estate lawyer.

Comment: Thanks, her loans are Federal, so that information helped a lot.

Comment: The OP raised the question of community property - isn't there some risk that this will apply in his case leaving him also directly liable for the credit card debts?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Because of the varying property laws between states and the unique situation of the two spouses living in separate states, where one is a community property state and the other is not, this very specific case depends entirely on how aggressively the credit card companies decide to pursue the collection (usually depends on the amount). As I mentioned, contacting an estate lawyer would be the best course of action for this very specific situation.

Comment: Makes sense - might be helpful to edit the answer to make clear that it does consider that aspect of the scenario. I also found it a bit hard to understand "Private loans are not required to discharge debts upon the death of a borrower".

Comment: Edited to be more clear, and to directly address the community property / split residency issues that OP noted

Comment: Apologies for being slow, but I'm still not sure I fully understand your answer. I thought it was normal for debts to be enforceable against the debtor's estate, though as you say student loans are often a special case. As I understand community property, it could produce the additional result that the debts can also be enforced against the surviving spouse as well as the debtor's estate - is that right? As you say, in either case whether the bank etc choose to enforce may be the most important point.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Only property jointly owned by the spouses is subject to collections, unless the spouse was a cosigner or joint account. The trick with OP's situation is that he and his wife are split across two states, which makes identifying jointly-owned assets a difficult task, hence the estate lawyer.

Comment: @Noah, I thought that "community property" states went further than that - see e.g. http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/debt-marriage-owe-spouse-debts-29572.html

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam If both OP and his spouse were residents of the same state, then the identification of community property/OPs financial obligations to pay the debts would become very easy. Since they reside in different states, there's no information about if one states' property laws overrule another's when spouses are residents of different states. Because OP is in a community property state and OP's wife is not, there's no clear-cut answer on whether he is responsible for the debt. His state says yes, hers says no.

Comment: Right - the bit that confuses me about your answer is this "they may attempt to collect against your wife's estate (community property)", which implies to me that even if community property does come into play, potential collections would be limited to the wife's estate and would not include the OP.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Credit cards / private loans are loans against a person's estate. In the case of a community property state, the wife's estate may include OP's (income, property, etc.). In the case of a common law property state, the wife's estate is limited to her own.